# preventDefault() in a keydown event, onchange event not trigger

Tags: javascript, onchange, keypress, keydown, preventdefault

The `preventDefault()` called in a keydown or keypress event with value programmatically changed does not consider changing and does not trigger the onchange event at the exit of the input text.

Example code:

```
$('#textbox1').on('change', function() {
    alert('onchange called');
});

$('#textbox1').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.key=='a') {

      $(this).val('A');
      //event.target.value = 'A';
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

After a call of onchange (leaving the input text) digit only the char 'a' and leaving the input another time.

Fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/gxx5744s/1/

What does use the onchange event to check if a value has changed? A pair of old / new value variables? a boolean?
Can be possible interact with it?

Keydown event default probably also does this.

Comment: I guess triggering `onchange` is part of the `default` you are preventing. By the way, what's your question? Do you want to know how trigger the onchange manually after your actions?

Comment: If i manually trigger the onchange event it is called every time and not only when I leave the focus of the input with the value changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the idea of @Kaddath a revised solution a bit "dirty" but working might be.
I do not like much but at the moment I did not find it better.

```js
$('#textbox1').on('change', function() {
 alert('onchange called');
});
    
$('#textbox1').on('keydown', function(event) {    
  var oldValue = event.target.value;
  
  if (event.keyCode == 46) { //DELETE
   event.target.value = ""
    } else
  event.target.value = event.key + event.target.value;
    
  event.preventDefault();

  if (event.target.valueOnFocus === undefined) {
    // set a new property on the input element
    event.target.valueOnFocus = oldValue;
    
    $(event.target).on('focus', function(event) {
      // From the second time that enter on the input element,
      // update the new property
      event.target.valueOnFocus = event.target.value;
    });
    
   $(event.target).on('blur', function(event) {
      if (event.target.value !== event.target.valueOnFocus)
        $(event.target).trigger('change');
   });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
```

On fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gxx5744s/3/

Answer (score 1):

from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change):

> Depending on the kind of form element being changed and the way the user interacts with the element, the change event fires at a different
>   moment:

- **When the element loses focus after its value was changed**, but not
  commited (e.g. after editing the value of `<textarea>` or `<input
  type="text">`).

This is the case in your example.

Try changing the value and unfocus, you'll see the alert.

Comment: That is not the point! The event is fired when the textinput gets out of focus, but not after hitting "a", where the function is called, but it should be fired then too, the prevent default should not prevent that...

Comment: Your way works, but when you change the event to "blur" instead of "change" it will fire every time the input loose focus not only after a change of the value!!!

Comment: In fact, the situation is more complex than the example and on the onchange event I have to call a listener on server side.
I wanted to avoid invoking it on the blur event but only on the onchange event.
I confirm that with the blur event is a good solution but is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The onchange event normally is fired after you change the value of the text input when it then gets out of focus, as it is the case here too... But it is not fired when the function with the preventDefault is called, which is not quite the expected behaviour!!!

The preventDefault should prevent the default behaviour of the keydown event on which it is called not of the onchange event, which actually cannot be cancelled...

I guess the problem is something different:

The default setting of the value seems to differ from the JQuery way with

`$(this).val('A');`

Maybe because just the value for a submit is changed not the DOM element... If you change this line to

`$(this).attr('Value','A');`

it behaves as expected!

Interesting thing is, that the default behaviour is not setting the attribute value neither and both ways change the display too, but there must be a difference!

EDIT: To me the solution form @Kaddath seems to be most suitable:

```js
var change = false;

$('#textbox1').on('change', function() {
  alert('onchange called');
});

$('#textbox1').on('blur', function() {
  if (change) {
    alert('"onchange" called too');
    change = false;
  }
});

$('#textbox1').on('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key == 'a') {
    $(this).val('A');
    change = true;
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
```

Comment: now that's interesting, definetly something to remember! after a look at the docs, i can confirm: "Setting values using this method (or using the native value property) does not cause the dispatch of the change event. For this reason, the relevant event handlers will not be executed. If you want to execute them, you should call .trigger( "change" ) after setting the value." ([from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/))

Comment: Attribute value is only for preset the value on first display the input text. Not work for modify the display value.

Comment: For Kaddath: If i manually trigger the onchange event it is called every time and not only when I leave the focus of the input with the value changed.

Comment: @Gian yes, of course triggering it takes effect immediately. What you can do is create a state variable to remember that there was a change, and implement a `blur` function on your element. In the blur function, check the state and if needed, trigger the change, then clear the state var. (edit: there might be a way to "notify' there was a change without blur, but i don't know it)

Comment: The fact is that the real case is a bit more complex and what I need to do is a generic function to apply if needed on some text inputs that might also have the attached onchange event.
Hooking up the blur event with the variable is a good solution but it may also happen that the onchange is called 2 times: one from blur and one from the input text.

Comment: Maybe we need a little more information what exactly should be done in your case!? :D

Comment: Taken out of context the @Kaddath's solution is good.
But if the main function is a "generic function", to use on the need for input text not controlled by me and another user hooked up other events, it could create side effects.
Probably rifine it a bit and testing it in many user cases is a good workaround.

Comment: The solution with onblur does not behave in the same way as the onchange because if I enter in the input text, modifies the value and then rewritten the initial value, the boolean variable is true.
In "default" mode, the onchange event in this case is not invoked.
I can not store the value of the input text on enter in it to compare it to the output because the function could be hooked to so many input texts on the page.
I should memorize the input value in an array or property of the input text, but really the solution becomes more "dirty".
Anyway thanks to everyone.