# Event onchange not triggered after use preventDefault() on keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have a `keydown` event where I make some changes to the input and change the value directly in the code. For this to work I need to use `preventDefault()`, otherwise the type I click ends up being duplicated in the input.
I found a similar case with this problem and I used the same solution that was proposed, and it worked:

[preventdefault-in-a-keydown-event-onchange-event-not-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825587/preventdefault-in-a-keydown-event-onchange-event-not-trigger)

```js
$('.test').on('change', function(event) {
    console.log('## run change')
});

const symbolDecimal = '.';
const ignorables = [8, 9, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46, 109, 189];

$(".test").on('keydown', function(event) {
 const oldValue = event.target.value;
  // debugger;
  // Caso for alguma tecla alfabética sem estar segurando a tecla Control, ignora o comando
  const key = event.key;
  const $input = $(event.target);

  // Inibi alguns eventos especiais
  if (event.ctrlKey || (event.ctrlKey && (key.toLowerCase() === 'v' || key.toLowerCase() === 'a' )) ) {
    return;
  }

  // Captura precisão do input
  const precisao = 0;
  // Monta a regex para a máscara
  const mask = new RegExp("(\\-)?(\\d+)(\\d{"+precisao+"})$", 'g');

  // Captura posição inicial e final do cursos no input
  const start = $input.prop('selectionStart');
  const end = $input.prop('selectionEnd');
  // Distribui os caracteres do input em um buffer
  let arr = $input.val().split('');

  // Verifica se existe precisão e monta o retorno conforme é montado a regex
  let masked = '$1$2';
  if (precisao > 0)
    masked = '$1$2.$3';

  // Inicia o valor
  let value = $input.val();
  // Verifica se o número é negativo
  if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
    // Se for Backspace e o curso estiver na posição 0 do input só retornar
    if (event.keyCode === 8 && start === 0 && end === 0) return;

    // Calcula a diferença entre a área selecionada no Input
    let diff = start === end ? 1 : end - start;
    // Se não for área selecionada
    //     Se for Backspace, posiciona a remoção a um caractere anterior da posição do cursor
    //     Se for Delete, posiciona a remoção a um caractere posterior da posição do cursos
    let initStart = start === 0 ? 0 : start - 1;
    if (event.keyCode === 46) initStart = start;

    // Verifica se o caracter a ser removido simbolo decimal
    if (arr[initStart] === symbolDecimal) {
      initStart -= 1;
    }

    // Remove o(s) caracter(s) na posição que o selector está ou os valores selecionados
    arr.splice(initStart, diff);
    value = arr.join('');
    // Aplica a máscara no valor
    $input.val(value.replace(mask, masked));
    // Mantém o cursor na posição em que estava quando disparou evento de remoção
    $input[0].setSelectionRange(initStart, initStart);
  } else if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
    // Adiciona novo número ao buffer
    arr.push(key);
    value = arr.join('');
    value = value.replace(mask, masked);
    // Aplica a máscara no valor

    $input.val(value);
  }
  // THIS PREVENTDEFAULT 
   event.preventDefault();
   
   // THE SOLUTION
   if (event.target.valueOnFocus === undefined) {
        event.target.valueOnFocus = oldValue;
        $(event.target).on('focus', function(event) {
            event.target.valueOnFocus = event.target.value;
        });

        $(event.target).on('blur', function(event) {
            if (event.target.value !== event.target.valueOnFocus)
                $(event.target).trigger('change');
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" name="test" class="test">
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/brunoobatista/5qox42dm/25/)

If I comment out the part where the **THE SOLUTION** is, the `onchange` event stops working. If I comment out the `preventDefault()` that is above this **THE SOLUTION**, the `onchange` event works, but the type that is pressed appears duplicated in the input.

My problem is similar to the code proposed in this other post, but it is already old and I haven't found anyone with a better solution or that seems correct.

My question is, why is the `onchange` event being cancelled? And why, if you don't use `preventDefault()`, is the value inserted twice in the Input? I only tested `onblur` event and it worked, but it wouldn't suit me for what I need to do.

Comment: Please post the code you are asking about right here in this question.

Comment: The `change` event is triggered by the browser. Changes to a DOM element's value through code doesn't trigger the `change` event`.

Comment: I put my code, it's similar to the other problem's link where I found a palliative solution.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the only decision that I found was creating such function:

```
function reload () {
  $("#myButton").unbind("click")
  $("#myButton").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }) 
}
```

Just `preventDefault` doesn't work, I don't know why...